# Plenty exceptions when using webbrowser control c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, embed

I am using `webbrowser-control` to display multiple webpages in a C# form.
Several webpages are giving me 100+ errors like:

```
First-chance exception Microsoft C++ exception: 
    Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location xxx
```

How can I catch or suppress these exceptions? There are so many my program is crashing.

Comment: Fix whatever is causing the errors. :)

Comment: This is extremely vague. With the amount of information you've provided, we can be of no assistance to you. I'm not even sure what the question is for that matter. Are you asking about what the errors/exceptions are? Are you asking how to catch & make them go away? Are you asking how to fix them?

Comment: The exceptions are from bad formatted websites. I have no influence on them. But they crash my application and I try to circumvent that somehow...

Comment: Does the application actually crash or do you just see script errors in the output/.. window?

Comment: It crashes after approx. 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress JavaScript errors by setting the **WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed =True**

Comment: Thanks.I tried that but the result stays the same. Any oher ideas?
The debug window is flooded with these errors.